# Cron-Job does not execute the php phar

Tags: php, bash, cron

I am totally helpless and sheer despair.

After I created the following crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PHAR="/usr/bin/php -f /home/heimathafen/customfiles/scripts/7d2d.phar"
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/15 * * * * ${PHAR} maintenance
*/5 * * * * ${PHAR} monitor
#50 3,7,11,15,19,23 * * * ${SDTD} reboot
#0 * * * * ${PHAR} backup
#55 23 * * 6 ${PHAR} creategifts
* * * * * ${PHAR} gameevents 0
* * * * * ( sleep 10; ${PHAR} gameevents 1)
* * * * * ( sleep 20; ${PHAR} gameevents 2)
* * * * * ( sleep 30; ${PHAR} gameevents 3)
* * * * * ( sleep 40; ${PHAR} gameevents 4)
* * * * * ( sleep 50; ${PHAR} gameevents 5)
```

I found that none of these jobs are executed.
When I run the command on the CLI:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /home/homeport/customfiles/scripts/7d2d.phar monitor
```

everything works fine. No matter if I put an `sh -c "..."` around it or just run it like that.

The phar file has the right permissions ( `chmod a+x` ) and the path is correct.
Also the crontab is in the usercontext (homeport).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried just pasting the full command line onto each crontab entry, rather than using the $PHAR env var?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried that ... same result. Nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have any output from the commands? https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep CRON`


```
Jul  3 17:11:01 dwarfserver CRON[1997560]: (heimathafen) CMD (( sleep 30; ${PHAR} gameevents 3))
Jul  3 17:11:01 dwarfserver CRON[1997562]: (heimathafen) CMD (( sleep 50; ${PHAR} gameevents 5))
Jul  3 17:11:01 dwarfserver CRON[1997564]: (heimathafen) CMD (( sleep 20; ${PHAR} gameevents 2))
Jul  3 17:11:01 dwarfserver CRON[1997563]: (heimathafen) CMD (( sleep 10; ${PHAR} gameevents 1))
```

But the output of Script (which should happen) is empty. But this is exactly my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`*/15 * * *` doesn't look like a valid interval.

Assuming that you want to execute your command at every 15th minute, you should also specify the day of the week.

Crontab entry structure:

```
# ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
# │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
# │ │ ┌───────────── day of the month (1 - 31)
# │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of the week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday;
# │ │ │ │ │                                   7 is also Sunday on some systems)
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# * * * * * <command to execute>
```

This might be useful: https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Sorry ... for whatever reason, a few `*` got lost during copying.
The job is executed, but without doing anything.
I have adjusted the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I found it and would love to whip myself.
After countless debugs I came across this line:

```
define('SERVER_USERNAME', trim(getenv('USER')));
```

Of course, this works beautifully if you don't run it with cron, because `$USER` is empty there.

I replaced it with:

```
define('SERVER_USERNAME', trim(exec('whoami')));
```

and lo and behold. Everything works.